# WPF MVVM Determine When Item in Collection On Model Changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a list of `Job` Models. The `Job` Model has a `JobName` property.

I can tell when a row is selected because the grid's `SelectedItem` is set, But when the user changes some data in the grid, I'd like to do some things in the view model.

When the user changes the `JobName` on the active row in the grid, how can the View Model know about it?

Comment: Adding a very concise code sample here could do a lot to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a two way binding the JobName property setter of your JobModel instance will be invoked. If the setter raises the PropertyChanged event you can handle that event in the ViewModel by  registering and unregistering the handler when the selected item changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JobName` property should something like:

```
public string JobName
{
    get { return _jobName; }
    set
    {
        _jobName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("JobName");
    }
}
```

When user changes it the datagrid, the setter will be called and you can add some logic there. Binding should be `TwoWay` (as is by default) for this to work.

If you need to listen to property changes in your viewmodel, an easy way is to add this in the constructor:

```
jobModel.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(JobModel_PropertyChanged);
```

Then in the `JobModel_PropertyChanged` method you can check which property has changed and react.

Comment: OK, but where/how in the view model do I detect a property change?

Comment: This won't help because this allows the grid to be notified of changes in the model, not the viewmodel getting notifications from the model.

Comment: I think what I want it to handle a Job_PropertyChanged event in the VM. But the Jobs are coming back from the DAL, so where/how do I wire up the event handler in the VM??

Comment: @kmarois, the 'OnPropertyChanged' method will fire an event to notify listeners.

Comment: @naxcto - Yes, but HOW is it coded in the VM?? What does the syntax look like? How do I wire it up?

Comment: @kmarois, are you implementing 'INotifyPropertyChanged' in your model?

Answer (score 1):

Have your model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then when you fill the Job list from your DAL register your model items with your propertyChanged event handler

**View Model Class:**

```
public class JobsViewModel
{
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public JobsViewModel()
    {
        //Get your list of items and add your handler method for each item that is added
        Jobs = new List<Job>();
        Job job = new Job("Joe");
        job.PropertyChanged += job_PropertyChanged;
        Jobs.Add(job);

    }

    private void job_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff with job here
    }
}
```

**Job Class:**

```
public class Job : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _jobName;
    public string JobName 
    {
        get { return _jobName; }
        set
        {
            _jobName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("JobName");
        }
    }

    public Job(string jobName)
    {
        JobName = jobName;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```